# Llamar un metodo de una clase a otra clase

Tags: python, python-3.x

Soy nuevo en python, estoy tratando de llamar el programa Correo.py dentro del programa Grafica.py. Quiero que se llame el programa Correo.py cada que se recibe un dato en el otro programa. Por ejemplo: Grafica.py recibe un valor de la base de datos de MySql(Estos se envían cada 20 segundos) y después de esto el programa lo que hace es graficar ese valor, ahí debería de enviar un correo electrónico si el valor sobrepasa los 25 °C.

Estos son los dos programas en python:

**Correo.py**
Este programa envía un correo si la temperatura pasa de los 25 °C. Estos datos se reciben de una base de datos en mysql y esta a la vez recibe valores de unos sensores cada 20 seg. El programa se detiene por 20 segundos.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import os.path
import time
import MySQLdb
import pandas as pd


dataSQL = []
sql_conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'DB')
cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT value,timestamp FROM sensorParser where sensor='TC'")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
dataSQL.append(list(row))
labels = ['value','timestamp']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dataSQL, columns=labels)
X = df['timestamp']
Y = df['value'].astype(float)


if (float(df['value'][0]) > 26):
    email = 'email@gmail.com'
    password = 'pass'
    send_to_email = 'email@gmail.com'
    subject = 'ALERTA!!!! SENSORES'
    message = 'Los valores de las variables criticas han superado el limite'
    file_location = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\prograpython\\car.jpg'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email
    msg['To'] = send_to_email
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

    filename = os.path.basename(file_location)
    attachment = open(file_location, "rb")
    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

    msg.attach(part)

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
    server.quit()

time.sleep(20)
```

**Grafica.py**

Este programa grafica los datos de los sensores en tiempo real obtenidos de la misma base de datos que la del otro programa.

```
@app.callback(Output('example-graph', 'figure'), 
          #events=[Event('graph-update', 'interval')])
          [Input('graph-update', 'interval')])


def update_graph_scatter(interval):

dataSQL = []
X = deque(maxlen=10)    
Y = deque(maxlen=10)

sql_conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'DB')
cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT value,timestamp FROM sensorParser where sensor='TC'")
#and timestamp >= timestamp()-4seg"
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    dataSQL.append(list(row))
    labels = ['value','timestamp']
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dataSQL, columns=labels)
    X = df['timestamp']
    Y = df['value'].astype(float)


    **"LLAMADA PARA ENVIAR EL CORREO ELECTRÓNICO"**


data = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
        x=list(X),
        y=list(Y),
        name='TEMP',
        mode= 'lines+markers',

        )
return {'data': [data],'layout' : go.Layout(title="TEMPERATURA",xaxis=dict(range=[min(X),max(X)]),
                                            yaxis=dict(range=[min(Y),max(Y)]),)}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: solo debes importarlo con `import Correo`

Comment: Muchas gracias Bryro, pero como hago la llamada a Correo.py?, como va a saber Grafica.py cuando llamar a Correo.py?